# Can't scrape an image link which is available in page source from a webpage

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to fetch the recipe image link from a [webpage](https://www.yumm.ca/en/recipe/salmon-green-curry-1) using xmlhttp requests. The image link is available within page source within some style attribute.
However, when I try like the following, I get `background-image` as an output whereas the value of style contains the image link.

I've tried so far:

```
Sub GrabImageLink()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.yumm.ca/en/recipe/salmon-green-curry-1"
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, Http As Object
    
    Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With Http
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Debug.Print HTML.querySelector(".recipe-visual").getAttribute("style")
End Sub
```

Current output:

```
background-image
```

Expected output:

```
https://cdn.yumm.ca/uploads/images/572b58ad0ed35a3d0294484ec535a131/salmon-green-curry@2x_s.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similarly annoying in JS. To get an attribute value you have to refer to the style property directly, so use following and it works:

```
HTML.querySelector(".recipe-visual").Style.backgroundImage
```

The code editor actually gives you the pop up for all available attribute once you have typed `HTML.querySelector(".recipe-visual").Style` which is handy